# Is there a place to get timing stats for historic games?

Tags: football

I am specifically interested in how much stoppage time was added to each half of a football game, for the major leagues, usually the first division in each country. An example list can be found here:
http://www.espnfc.com.au/scores?date=20150809

For example, on that date, in the match between [Salmohr and Bochum](http://www.espnfc.com.au/commentary/421183/commentary.html) there was definitely stoppage time as a goal was scored at (90+1), but no where in the espn site can I find out exactly how much time was added in each half.

Comment: wow, why the down votes?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as [requests for sources/research are off-topic](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on [Sports SE](https://sports.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detailed statistics like this are rarely available for free. You will have to apply to statistic keeping companies like Opta or Prozone and pay for whatever information you require.